# Looking to obtain the biggest difference between two values in a column and returning the winner?

Tags: python, pandas

```
TeamA  TeamB   City
12      18      12
17      15       5
19       8       7

df['diff'] = numpy.abs(data_frame['TeamA'] - data_frame['TeamB'])
max = data_frame['difference'].max()
```

I am stuck at finding the difference max. Now, what I am looking to do is to get the winning team which should be team A in this case and then get the city number associated with that win. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
diff = df['TeamA'] - df['TeamB']

max_row = diff.abs().idxmax()

team = 'Team A' if  diff.loc[max_row] > 0  else 'Team B'

city = df.loc[diff.abs().idxmax(), 'City']
```

Comment: In my code, `diff` is a pandas series. It should have an `.idxmax()` method. See it [in action](https://ideone.com/8FAv85).